# How to replace double in the string format in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

How to replace string with double for calculating "distance"(instead of time) in the below code in C#? Where distance is 0.00 initially. trying to post the values through Sqlite in Windows Phone.

```
private string time = string.Empty;
        public string Time
        {
            get { return time; }
            set { if (SetProperty(ref time, value)) IsDirty = true; }
        }
```

// need to place the values in the below lines.

```
internal CustomerViewModel(int id, double pace, string time, double distance )
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.pace = pace;
            this.time = time;
            this.distance = distance;                      
            this.isDirty = false;
        }
```

Comment: I neither see `double` nor `distance` in the code you showed. You might want to improve your question.

Comment: Did you paste the wrong code?

Comment: Your edit doesn't make it any more clear.

Comment: Please read [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), follow the suggestions, and try again.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but is this what you mean:

```
private double time = 0.00;
    public double Time
    {
        get { return time; }
        set { if (SetProperty(ref time, value)) IsDirty = true; }
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
private double distance = 0.0;
    public double Distance
    {
        get { return this.distance; }
        set { 
            this.distance = value;
            IsDirty = true; }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't work.

Comment: @madhukumar - that is not a very helpful description of an error. Did you get an exception? If so, what was the exact message? If not, how exactly does it not "work"?

Comment: @madhukumar please tell me what you are trying and why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Recipe : please check now.

Comment: @madhukumar It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve. I **think** you want a new property for the distance? I have updated my answer with a new property to encapsulate distance.

Comment: @madhukumar If this is the answer you were looking for, please mark it as the correct answer. If not, please let me know what is wrong.

Comment: @Recipe: what you posted was ok. but still my application is not working.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829960/how-to-change-textbox-code-to-textblock-in-c-sharp-for-windows-phone  .check this link please. I want to post the values through Sqlite into next page inside LongListSelector.(using SQLiteWinRTPhone).